# Bootstrap submenu how can i close submenu 1 while I clicked submenu 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code for my collapse sub menu:

```
                <li class="sec1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#item3">
                    <a href="#">Item 3<span class="caret pull-right"></span></a>
                    <ul class="menu sub-menu collapse" id="item3">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3B</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sec1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#item4">
                    <a href="#">Item 4<span class="caret pull-right"></span></a>
                    <ul class="menu sub-menu collapse" id="item4">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 4A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 4B</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

The problem for me is that, if my Item 3 dropdown menu is already open, and when I click Item 4 menu, the Item 3 menu will still open. How do I make Item 3 dropdown menu close when I click on Item 4 menu? I only wan one item dropdown menu to open at a time.

Comment: Can you just replicate the problem in fiddle? because I do not find the problem in normal bootstrap template.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an `accordion`-like behavior.
You may have to restructure your html a little in order to achieve it.

1. Wrap your list in a parent having a unique `id`.
2. For each of your toggle elements, add a `panel` class (bootstrap accordion is dependent to this), and `data-parent="#parentIdHere"`.

Here is a sample of your updated code: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9wskghsg/)

NOTE:
- Since `panel` class is required, you may have to tweak this in order to override bootstrap styles.